# Django QuerySet not serializable

Tags: python, ajax, django, json, serialization

I have the following function I'm using to make `Ajax` calls:

```
 30 import json
 31
 32 def get_info(request):
 33    run = Run.objects.values('nvp_build', 'lports', 'lswitch_stt')
 34    measurements = Measurements.objects.values('maxfield')
 35    apistats = APIStats.objects.values('num')
 36    clusterdata = ClusterData.objects.values('memory_usage')
 37 
 38    response_data = json.dumps(run)
 39    return HttpResponse(response_data, mimetype='application/json')
```

so when make the call to that method in my `views.py` I get:

```
 [{'lports': 4056, 'nvp_build': u'31559', 'lswitch_stt': 2000}, 
     {'lports': 102, 'nvp_build': u'30194', 'lswitch_stt': 40}, 
     {'lports': 4056, 'nvp_build': u'31299', 'lswitch_stt': 2000}, 
     {'lports': 4056, 'nvp_build': u'31350', 'lswitch_stt': 2000}, 
     {'lports': 4056, 'nvp_build': u'31481', 'lswitch_stt': 2000}, 
     {'lports': 4056, 'nvp_build': u'31489', 'lswitch_stt': 2000}, 
     {'lports': 4056, 'nvp_build': u'31494', 'lswitch_stt': 2000}, 
     {'lports': 4056, 'nvp_build': u'31559', 'lswitch_stt': 2000}] 
   is not JSON serializable
```

However, when I run it manually, and utilize the above array and do `json.dumps()` it works ... 
any clues?

Comment: Are you using `json.dumps` in your code and testing manually with `json.dump` they aren't  the same.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda mistyped ... they are the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use django's built-in [serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/):

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse   


def get_info(request):
    data = serializers.serialize('json', 
                                 Run.objects.all(), 
                                 fields=('nvp_build', 'lports', 'lswitch_stt'))
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: TypeError at /graphs/get_info

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype' ... Not sure why I'm getting that error

Comment: `mimitype` actually is now (django 1.6) deprecated. I've replaced it with `content_type`. But, not sure why it didn't work with `mimetype`. Do you have the same `HttpResponse` import statement as I've provided?

Comment: the mimetype keyword argument is deprecated for a while. use content_type instead